# Most optimal Neptune query for getting all related vertices with the shortest distances

Tags: amazon-web-services, gremlin, tinkerpop, tinkerpop3, amazon-neptune

I need to get all related vertices with shortest distances to the given vertex, which distances does not exceed some maximum distance value.

I came up with the following query for maximum distance of 4, but is it possible to optimise this query more? Maybe there is some algorithm for graph distance searching in Neptune?

`g.V('XXX').repeat(both().dedup()).emit().times(4)
    .project('id', 'count').by(id()).by(path().count(local))`

Comment: Is the query you posted giving you what you need? If not could you say a bit more about what you need to achieve?  If you know the shape of your data you can also take a look at the new query hints that Neptune provides when doing repeat until type queries. Details are here: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/neptune/latest/userguide/gremlin-query-hints.html

Comment: I need to make calculation for a particular vertex. For it I need the shortest distances between this particular vertex **P** and other vertices. And I do not need the distances more than specified length (4 in this query). So the query right now works like the BFS - the number of loop is the distance of the vertex  to the the vertex **P**.

Comment: I modified the original one, put the loop number in the sack(), but I'm not sure, whether it will perform optimally  for checking already visited vertices via dedup().

`g.V('XXX').repeat(sack(assign).by(loops()).sack(sum).by(constant(1)).both().dedup()).emit().times(4).limit(10000).project('id', 'count').by(id()).by(sack()).timeLimit(100)`

Comment: In CYPHER there is a shortest path function - https://neo4j.com/docs/cypher-manual/current/execution-plans/shortestpath-planning/

Answer (score 2):

I see two issues that would affect the performance in your query.

1. it uses path tracking (expensive, hence slow)
2. It revisits the initial vertex, you probably don't want it in your result

This is what I would do instead:

```
g.V('XXX').as('x').
  repeat(both().dedup().sack(assign).by(loops())).
    emit().
    times(4).
  where(neq('x')).
  project('id', 'count').
    by(id).
    by(sack()) // distances start at 0; if you want the distance to
               // start at 1, use sack(sum).by(constant(1)).sack()
```

Comment: Great. Thanks! That's the one I came up recently too (see my reply to the initial question). Cool that we came to the same solution. 

I ran this query on the graph with 10.000.000 of vertices, the one with sack works twice as fast as the one with path.

Comment: They're similar, not quite the same. My query only adds 1 in the end (if you want to start at 1, but this is something you could do in your application to improve the query performance) and I exclude the start vertex from the result (though, this could also be something you could do in your application).